# Append .txt file by cat inside the last exisiting line of another .txt file

Tags: bash, cat, text

I have a .txt file which I cat into another .txt file.

The last line of the original file (final.txt) ends with ***"lats ="*** and then by applying cat, the numbers below ***"lats ="*** are added, as shown below.

***The problem is that cat places the new data below "lats =".***

```
cat initial.txt >> final.txt
```

**Is there any flag I could use, so that cat places the new data on the same line as "lats ="?**

What I have:

```
          12.54000000  12.98000000  12.98000000  12.54000000
lats =
           9.90000000  10.34000000  10.34000000   9.90000000
          10.34000000  10.78000000  10.78000000  10.34000000
          10.78000000  11.22000000  11.22000000  10.78000000
          11.22000000  11.66000000  11.66000000  11.22000000
          11.66000000  12.10000000  12.10000000  11.66000000
          12.10000000  12.54000000  12.54000000  12.10000000
          12.54000000  12.98000000  12.98000000  12.54000000
```

What I need:

```
          12.54000000  12.98000000  12.98000000  12.54000000
lats =     9.90000000  10.34000000  10.34000000   9.90000000
          10.34000000  10.78000000  10.78000000  10.34000000
          10.78000000  11.22000000  11.22000000  10.78000000
          11.22000000  11.66000000  11.66000000  11.22000000
          11.66000000  12.10000000  12.10000000  11.66000000
          12.10000000  12.54000000  12.54000000  12.10000000
          12.54000000  12.98000000  12.98000000  12.54000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply specific `sed` substitution right after appending:

```
$ cat initial.txt >> final.txt
$ sed -Ei '/^lats =/N; s/\n\s{6}//' final.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, RomanPerekhrest! It works! However, how can I control that the new data after cat are pasted exactly next to "lats =", with no gap at all?

Comment: @MariaKarypidou, that's what the expression  `'/^lats =/N; s/\n\s{6}//` does. To remove all spaces - replace `\s{6}` with `\s+`

Comment: Thank you very much!